# How do I deploy a Web Site (NOT a Web Application) to Azure through Azure Web Role Accelerator?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have two VS 2010 projects. The 1st is an existing WEB Site while the 2nd is Web project. Should I select b) and ask for Publish I do have the option for Web Deploy to an Azure Web Role Accelerator service and it works fine.

But, I am not able to do the same for the 1st. There is no Publish option in the corresponding context menu, just "Publish Web Site ..." which is the old known one. I do not have the option to web deploy the site.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

You can't publish a web site to Azure directly.  Take a look at this for how to convert the site to an application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx

If you really need to publish a web site, you can try:

http://www.davidaiken.com/2010/07/14/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-web-site-to-windows-azure/